# How to get millis to midnigth at PST

Tags: java, java-time, timezone-offset

I need to get the number of milliseconds between now and midnight at "America/Los_Angeles" (PST).

```
midnightAtPST = ???;

long millis = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(now, midnightAtPST) ???
```

This is what I have for now, which gives an incorrect value:

```
LocalDateTime midnight = LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate().atStartOfDay().plusDays(1);
Instant midnigthPST = midnight.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")).toInstant();
Instant now = LocalDateTime.now().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

long millis = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(now, midnigthPST);
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're interested for the time in a specific zone, do not use a `LocalDateTime`, which does not have the notion of timezones, but use a `ZonedDateTime`.

You can obtain the current date in a given zone with the [`ZonedDateTime.now(zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) static factory. Then, you can have the date at midnight (on the next day) in a given timezone with the method [`atStartOfDay(zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) on the type `LocalDate`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
ZonedDateTime midnight = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(zoneId).plusDays(1);

long millis = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(now, midnight);
```

This will correctly return the number of milliseconds between the current date and the start of the next day in Los Angeles.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine, except for the `now` instant, which you convert to UTC timezone from your timezone, giving an offset that you don't want.

This should work as you expect:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```